# Why won't the Traders in Fairfax Gardens sell anything anymore?

Tags: fable-2

During the Archaeologist quest I noticed that all the gypsy traders in the Fairfax Gardens area have nothing to sell.  They'll buy things easily enough, but they never have anything to sell anymore.  Is there any way to fix this?  I think it happened to me once before years ago too and I found a way to fix it but I can't find anything through google now.